# $a\cdot b =|a||b| \cos\gamma \quad \cos\gamma=\cos(\varphi - \varphi ') \sin\theta \sin \theta '+\cos\theta \cos \theta'$

Tags: trigonometry

see [Spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines)

For two $a,b$ vectors in 3-dimensional  Euclidean space. if $\theta$,$\varphi$ and $\theta '$,$\varphi '$ are angular coordinates of $a$ and $b$ respectively.

$$a\cdot b =|a||b| \cos\gamma$$

Simplest way to show $\cos\gamma=\cos(\varphi - \varphi ') \sin\theta \sin \theta '+\cos\theta \cos \theta'$ $\quad$ without using tangents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$cos(\varphi-\varphi ')=cos\varphi cos\varphi'+sin\varphi sin\varphi'$

Use unit vectors $a,b$ i.e $|a|=1,|b|=1$

$a=(x,y,z)=(sin\theta cos\varphi,sin\theta sin\varphi,cos\theta)$

$b=(x',y',z')=(sin\theta' cos\varphi',sin\theta' sin\varphi',cos\theta')$

dot product over the $xy$ plane :

$cos(\varphi-\varphi ')=\frac {xx'+yy'}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}=\frac {xx'+yy'}{\sin\theta \sin\theta'}$

dot product $a.b$ : $\cos\gamma=xx'+yy'+zz'=xx'+yy'+cos\theta cos\theta'$

$\cos\gamma=cos(\varphi-\varphi ')\sin\theta \sin\theta'+cos\theta cos\theta$